# Where is normal edit modifier?

Tags: modifiers, normals

I want to have custom vertex normals. I have a brief search, and found the 
[official doc](http://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/modify/normal_edit.html). It claims that *Normal Edit Modifier* can do this, and it is placed in *Modify* column of all modifiers. However, in my blender program, the *Modify* column only has:

- Mesh Cache
- UV Project
- UV Wrap
- Vertex Weight Edit
- Vertex Weight Mix
- Vertex Weight Proximity

So where is the Normal Editor? Is it being deprecated? Or replaced by other stuffs?

I'm using Blender version 2.73.

Comment: What version of blender are you using?

Comment: @Denis Appended in question. I'm using blender 2.73.

Comment: I think Normal Edit Modifier was added in 2.74

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modifier you are looking for *[Normal Edit](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/modify/normal_edit.html)* is under the modify column in the modifiers list, but only in version 2.74 and higher.
As the [release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.74/Modeling) show that feature was added in 2.74.

<sub>This picture is showing version 2.75</sub>
[image: modifier list]